# MySQL combining some data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website using Advanced Custom Fields, if that helps at all.

I have two tables: `posts` and `postmeta`

**Posts**

```
|-------------------------------------------|
|   ID    |   post_title    |   post_type   |
|    1    |     Title 1     |       book    |
|    2    |     Title 1     |      product  |
|    3    |     Title 2     |       book    |
|    4    |     Title 2     |      product  |
|    5    |     Title 3     |       book    |
|    6    |     Title 3     |      product  |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

**Post Meta**

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|   post_id       |   meta_key      |      meta_value      |
|        3        |     Rating      |            *****     |
|        3        |    Publisher    |     Julian Celestro  |
|        3        |       Date      |     April 16, 1840   |
|        3        |       Type      |          Hardback    |
|        3        |       Price     |          19.99       |
|        3        |       ISBN      |       1234567890     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Of course there is a bunch of other stuff happening, but these are the relevant fields.

So in the posts table, there are 3 books, each with a book id# and a product id#.

The postmeta table contains the information about all of these books and products, by associating a meta key and value with a post id.

There are many many books, and I need a way to basically combine the two tables. For each post_title(book title) from table 1, I want the ID number that is associated with the post_type of product (id = 2,4,6) and I want to join that with the postmeta table.

So for example, I would like to have a MySQL statement  that results in returning:

```
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=rating, meta_value=*****
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=Publisher, meta_value=Julian Celestro
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=Date, meta_value=April 16, 1840
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=Type, meta_value=Hardback
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=Price, meta_value=19.99
ID=4, post_title='Title 2', meta_key=ISBN, meta_value=1234567890
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT `postmeta`.*
FROM `posts` 
RIGHT JOIN `postmeta` ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id
WHERE `post_type` = 'book'
```

and it is (expectedly) giving me the meta_key and meta_value that I want, but it gives me the post_id of the book instead of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Add another meta_key 'product_id' setting the meta_value as the ID of the product, and the post_id as the ID of the book.

then query that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value
FROM `posts` AS p 
RIGHT JOIN `postmeta` AS pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE `post_type` = 'book'
```

**Output**

```
ID  post_title  meta_key    meta_value
3   Title 2     Rating      *****
3   Title 2     Publisher   Julian Celestro
3   Title 2     Date        April 16, 1840
3   Title 2     Type        Hardback
3   Title 2     Price       19.99
3   Title 2     ISBN        1234567890
```

Comment: Looking for the output ID to be 4 in this scenario. I want the ID of the output to show the result of 
`SELECT p.id
FROM posts
WHERE post_type = 'product'`


But I want the rest of the output to be where post_type = 'book'

Comment: @akschoeck there is no relation between the book and the product except the title! which isn't a smart thing, check my answer again.

Comment: @Hakem is right. There should be a relation between these two tables.In your sample data, those meta values are assigned to post_Id = 3

Comment: @sqluser this is what he is trying to do: SELECT p.ID,prod.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value
FROM `posts` AS p 
RIGHT JOIN `postmeta` AS pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
JOIN `posts` AS prod ON prod.post_title = p.post_title
WHERE p.`post_type` = 'book'

Comment: Gonna try some of these suggestion in a few min. @Hakem, I'm a little confused at the alias usage of renaming posts to p and then again renaming posts to prod. Does the second alias declaration do something that leaving it as p wouldn't do?

Comment: @akschoeck it is a self join. because they are two different rows, Im sure there are other approaches, but for WordPress the approach in my separate answer is the easiest! you just save the product ID as meta :)